# migrating database from robo3t to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, robo3t

I currently have a database in Robo3T that I would like to migrate to MongoDB Atlas.
[image]

Specifically, I want to move new_selen_top200 to MongoDB Atlas.
How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Robo3T is GUI tool to work with the database; I think you are connecting to a database using Robo3T.

Comment: @prasad_ I want to move the new_selen_top200 to mongodb atlas